# CSS Background not working

Tags: css, background

I am trying to add a background using the following, placed inside custom.css:

```
}

body {
background-image: url("img/background.jpg");
}
```

custom.css is in folder HTML/css

background.jpg is in folder HTML/img

What should I do so that the background works? Right now it doesn't appear at all.

Answer (score 2):

Go up a level with your URL selector using `..`:

```
background-image: url("../img/background.jpg");
```

That will go up a level (to the `HTML` folder) and then find the `background.jpg` file in the `img` folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your 'img' folder is in a different directory to your 'css' folder.

Try

```
background-image: url("../img/background.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use :

```
body{
   background-image: url('../img/background.jpg');
}
```